# Python Panda DataFrame add column headers to data from clipboard dynamically

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I am copying data from my clipboard that contains no headers.  I dont want the index column and I want to name the columns dynamically skipping the first column by count(ie 1,2,3...).  The output data set would like the following below.

```
      1        2       3        4        5        6        7        8        9        10
1981  5012.0   8269.0  10907.0  11805.0  13539.0  16181.0  18009.0  18608.0  18662.0  18834.0
```

Here is the code I'm starting with.  The codes works but the column headers aren't dynamic and the data set may not always have the same number of columns. I'm not sure how to make the column headers be dynamic

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard(index_col = 0, names = ["","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"])
```

Comment: Does `pd.read_clipboard(header=None)` help?

Comment: or maybe `pd.read_clipboard(header=None).rename(columns=lambda x: x if x > 0 else '')` ..? Can you post your original data from your clipboard?

Comment: The data set doesn't have a header and i'm trying to add a header dynamically.

Comment: Please post a sample of the original data so we can copy to our clipboards too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get exactly what you are looking for you can use:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(header=None, index_col=0).rename_axis(None)
```